# jQuery event after dom tree change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using jQuery events like mouseover and mouseout.

When a user fires the mouseover on the target element, this element receives a new class (with removeClass and addClass).

Then, when the mouse gets out, mouseout is fired, but the selector of the element having the mouseout event doesn't match anymore, because I changed the class.

Example :

```
$('span.project_unsel').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('project_unsel');
    $(this).addClass('project_sel');
});
```

After firing the above event, class has changed and the following doesn't get fired.

```
$('span.project_sel').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('project_sel');
    $(this).addClass('project_unsel');
});
```

How can I tell jQuery to "update" or "bind" again too understand this ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Why dont you select by ID (or at least not the class name you're changing) then add remove the class?

Comment: because there are quite a few of these, and, I think "id" should be unique.

Comment: but you are right, I should use an "empty" class to select them

Comment: Yes, there should be one class name to allow you to target it. Another classname for selected/unselected.

Comment: mattimus, post it as an answer, I will give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest doing something like this instead, to makes things less confusing:

```
$('span.project').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

That is, bind `.hover` to elements with the class `.project`, and simply add and remove the `.selected` class when the mouseenter (first argument) and mouseleave (second argument) events are triggered.

Take a look at [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to fix this, but if you want to minimize your code changes you can just add another class to your target elements that doesn't change, then bind to that.

If you can't add an additional class for some reason, try this:

```
$('span.project_sel,span.project_unsel').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('project_sel').addClass('project_unsel');
}).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('project_unsel').addClass('project_sel');
});
```

You could also take a look at `toggleClass()` if you feel add/remove is inelegant.

Edit: Karim's hover solution is better than doing it via mouseout/mouseover.